# What does "$f(x,y)$ is strictly increasing in each argument" imply?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Say we have a function $f(x,y)$. below are what we know about $f(x,y)$

- **strictly increasing in each argument**.
- $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers only, i.e., $0, 1, 2, ...$

Now we have a fixed number $z$ which is also a natural number and we want to find out all values of $x$ and $y$ which satisfy $f(x,y)=z$.

---

**My question:**

1. Is $x \leq z,$ $y \leq z$ implied from the above two conditions? and Why?
2. Is $f(x,y) \geq x + y$ implied also? and Why?

Comment: Hint: Induction.

Comment: Why would one want to use induction in this case?

Comment: You should specify the range of the function $f$, for instance $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, which would rule out some of the couterexamples below. (In other words, if the values of $f$ must be natural numbers too, as it seems based on your thesis)

Comment: @rewritten That is a (quite important) point you're making. Jack, you should unaccept my answer as my counterexample allows for $z$ to not be a natural number.

Comment: @hejseb It's technically the best way to prove 1. and 2., and you can only hide the induction - it isn't true for, say, strictly increasing function on positive rationals.

Comment: Is this question based on chapter 3 of pearls of functional algorithm design? Because I'm asking the same questions.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I don't think the previous two answers are correct. You can prove this. Lets restate facts:

$$
x, y, z \in \mathbb{N} \\
f(x, y) = z \\
x < k \Rightarrow f(x, y) < f(k, y) \\ 
y < k \Rightarrow f(x, y) < f(x, k)
$$

With these four facts we can prove the second part by induction:

For $x = y = 0$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x + y & \le f(x, y) \\
\therefore 0 & \le f(0, 0) & \text{by substitution} \\
\forall z \in \mathbb{N} ~~~ f(x, y) = z & \Longrightarrow f(x, y) \ge 0 & \text{because the natural numbers are from zero up}\\
\therefore 0 & \le f(0, 0)
\end{aligned}
$$

So with the zero case proven we can now try the induction step. We need to prove that if $x + y \le f(x, y)$ then it is true that $(x + 1) + y \le f(x + 1, y)$:

Lets work on the initial step first:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x + y & \le f(x, y) & \text{given} \\
x + 1 + y & \le f(x, y) + 1 & \text{add one to both sides}
\end{aligned}
$$

And now lets work on what we need to prove:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x, y) & < f(x + 1, y) & \text{by the increasing property of the first argument} \\
\therefore f(x, y) + 1 & \le f(x + 1, y) & \text{adding one to the left makes it possibly equal because this is the set of natural numbers} \\
\therefore (x + y) + 1 & \le f(x + 1, y) & \text{by substitution of the induction assumption}
\end{aligned}
$$

And that is it, we have proven that it is true for the first argument of f and hopefully you can see that it will be true for the second argument of f by symmetry.

I decided to prove this myself once I saw it given as true in Chapter 3 of [Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521513383).

Comment: As stated in the comments, this relies on the (pretty reasonable) assumption that the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**: Strictly increasing in each argument means 
$$f(x,y) < f(z,y) \text{ for } x < z$$ and
$$f(x,y) < f(x,z) \text{ for } y < z.$$
Therefore you cannot imply that $x \leq z, y \leq z$ from the above. 
For 2., this is neither true.

Answer (score 0):

None of these are implied. Take for example $$
  f(x,y) = x + y - 1 \text{.}
$$

Then for $x=y=0$, $f(x,y) = -1 < x,y$ and $f(x,y) = -1 < 0 = x+y$.